# Holding site position while showing / hiding items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Have problem with moving page to the top when I show or hide items. I want to show and hide containers simultaneously force site to don't scroll it up to the top when action of showing / hiding is triggered.

```js
<!--
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
//-->
```

```css
p{
  padding: 400px 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>test</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<html>
<body>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('movie1');">Movie 1</a>
    <div id="movie1" hidden>
        <video id="ad" width="1920" height="1080" controls>
            <source src="video/movie1.avi" type="video/avi">
            too old browser.
        </video>
    </div>
  
    <br/>
  
    <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('movie2');">Movie 2</a>
    <div id="movie2" hidden>
        <video id="ad" width="1920" height="1080" controls>
            <source src="video/movie2.avi" type="video/avi">
            too old browser.
        </video>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How to prevent this move? Is there any other solution or I need to change toggle script?

Comment: can you please provide more about this or just make jsfiddle

Comment: you can run code from snippet but okay here we go: https://jsfiddle.net/3wrq3sce/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/ftqo2z68/

Remove `href=#` from anchor tags.

**JS:-**

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    $("#"+id).toggle();
}
```

**HTML:-**

```
<p>Lorem ipsum</p> <a onclick="toggle_visibility('movie1');">Movie 1</a>

<div id="movie1" hidden>
    <video id="ad" width="1920" height="1080" controls>
        <source src="video/movie1.avi" type="video/avi">too old browser.</video>
</div>
<br/> <a onclick="toggle_visibility('movie2');">Movie 2</a>

<div id="movie2" hidden>
    <video id="ad" width="1920" height="1080" controls>
        <source src="video/movie2.avi" type="video/avi">too old browser.</video>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe not important in this case, but doesn't removing the href attr also remove a lot of default styling that comes with links?  Named anchors without href just look like text, and don't have color, underlines, hover/active effects, etc.

If that is important, I would suggest href="javascript:void(0)".

Comment: @wwwmarty Yes we can use `javascript:void(0);`